# Selecting parts of mesh for UV with mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm trying to get a uv map for this shirt by selecting it (it uses EA's template for Sims 4). I have the mirror modifier on and I can't seem to select these parts. They also don't show up selected in the UV (modifier doesn't apply to it). How can I select these parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select those parts if you apply the modifier in object mode as shown below:

[image]

If you need the modifier and want to keep it, whatever you do in the UV Editor will be mirrored.

Comment: Hi. Your image seems to be missing, could you update the link? Please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)